# Sending a csv file via POST request with vba

Tags: excel, vba, csv, post

I am currently trying to send a csv file to a database via a POST request, but every time I send the POST request the request body is empty. I've tried switching the headers around to "application/json", but I receive a formatting error that I do not know how to remedy.

Here is the code:

```
Sub macroPOST()
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = "some file path"
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Url = "some url"
    With objHTTP
        .Open "POST", Url, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/csv"
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
        .Send filePath
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```vb
Sub macroPOST()
    
    Dim objHTTP, FSO As Object, TS As Object

    Const URL = "some url"
    Const filePath = "some path"

    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If FSO.FileExists(filePath) Then
 
        Set TS = FSO.opentextfile(filePath, 1)
   
        With objHTTP
            .Open "POST", URL, False
            .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/csv"
            .Send TS.Readall
             TS.Close
             'Debug.Print objHTTP.Status, objHTTP.StatusText, objHTTP.responseText
        End With
        
     Else
         MsgBox "'" & filePath & "' not found", vbCritical, "File not found"
     End If

End Sub
```

Code tested using this node.js server

```vb
const http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
if (request.method == 'POST') {
    var body = '';
    request.on('data', function (data) { body += data });
    request.on('end', function () {
    try {
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.end(body);
        return;
    } catch (err){
        response.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.end("Error");
        return;
    }});
}});
server.listen(3000);
console.log("listening on 3000")
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I tried using the above code, but it seems the request body is still empty when making the post request. The requests themselves return a 200 code and the success message, but the request obj received by the server has no body.

Comment: @moon Are you sure the format is correct for the server to accept it ?

Comment: I just set up a simple node server with some basic routes to receive the requests. Is this just a parsing issue? I feel like the csv file is being sent in the request, but perhaps I am not using the appropriate parsers to read the data on node.

Comment: @moon I have updated reply with node.js test server