# "Invalid multipart payload format" via HTTPRequest with VBA despite identical payload to successful browser initiated requests

Tags: excel, vba, httpwebrequest, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload files to a web service using VBA, following the form-data multipart structure sent when uploading documents via web browser, however I'm receiving the "400: Invalid multipart payload format" response, despite sending (from what i can tell) an identical payload in the request.

For my test case I've created a txt document named test.txt that contains "TestContents" within. I've uploaded this file using the web browser and have also attempted this with VBA (shown below). Spending some time comparing the payload from Chrome with my own VBA generated payload i can't see any differences.

I'm using the following code to create and send the multipart payload to the web service (URL partly obfuscated) and have used the following question to help re-write this a few times in the pursuit of solving this issue: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110601/upload-a-picture-to-file-io-http-post-in-vba]

(Apologies for any mess within - I've been changing and re-writing this for quite while now so there might be some untidyness)

```
Private Function toArray(inData As String)

    Dim objADODB As Object: Set objADODB = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    
     objADODB.Type = 2
     objADODB.Charset = "_autodetect"
     objADODB.Open
     objADODB.WriteText (inData)
     objADODB.Position = 0
     objADODB.Type = 1
     toArray = objADODB.Read()

     Set objADODB = Nothing
End Function

Private Function readBinary(filePath As String)

    Dim objADODB As Object: Set objADODB = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    
    objADODB.Type = 1
    objADODB.Open
    objADODB.LoadFromFile filePath
    readBinary = objADODB.Read
    objADODB.Close
    
    Set objADODB = Nothing
End Function

Public Sub sendDocument(ByVal inID As String, ByVal tags As String, ByVal docContentType As String, ByVal docFilePath As String)

     Dim objADODB As Object
     Dim objHTTP As Object
    
     Dim boundary As String: boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundaryeeYChAY7UlBEI63d" 'Set like this so i can debug like-for-like with browser payload
     Dim docFileName As String: docFileName = Mid(docFilePath, InStrRev(docFilePath, "\") + 1)

     '(structure is file, material, tags if there are any)
     Set objADODB = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    
     With objADODB
         .Type = 1
         .Open
        
         .Write toArray("--" & boundary & Chr(10))
         .Write toArray("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""; filename=""" & docFileName & """" & Chr(10) & _
                 "Content-Type: " & docContentType & Chr(10) & Chr(10))
         .Write readBinary(docFilePath)
         .Write toArray(Chr(10) & "--" & boundary & Chr(10))
         .Write toArray("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""material""" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & inID & Chr(10))
         If tags <> "" Then .Write toArray("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""tags""" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & tags & Chr(10))
         .Write toArray("--" & boundary & "--")
         .Position = 0
     End With

     If Not validateID(inID) Then
         MsgBox ("ID must be 4-5 digits long")
         Exit Sub
     End If
    
     If auth = "" Then
         MsgBox "Login is required. Click OK to log in"
         Call getAuth
     End If
    
     Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    
     With objHTTP
         .Open "POST", "https://xxx.xxx/hapi/document", False
         .setRequestHeader "Authorization", auth
         .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & boundary
         .send (objADODB.Read())
         MsgBox .responseText
     End With
    
     bStatusOK = objHTTP.status = 200
    
     If objHTTP.status = 401 Then
         MsgBox ("Login is invalid/expired. Please reauthenticate")
         Call getAuth
     End If
End Sub
```

The above produces a payload identical to what is present in Chrome's inspector window when viewing form data for the request, which is:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryeeYChAY7UlBEI63d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

TestContents
------WebKitFormBoundaryeeYChAY7UlBEI63d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="material"

16145
------WebKitFormBoundaryeeYChAY7UlBEI63d--
```

I'm starting to suspect that it's not encoded correctly. I note that the browser call uses the header

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

..which when i attempt to replicate this or any single type (except br), I still get the same message but replied in a format that the VBA locals window cannot understand. I have had success with other POST and PUT requests sending JSON or text payloads without needing to specify Accept-Encoding so I'm not sure if this is the right path to continue on.

If anybody is able to provide some help on this I would be incredibly grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `vbCrLF` in place of `Chr(10)`

Comment: Aargh it was the simplest thing that got me, this has worked a charm thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a tags parameter it will be missing the start boundary.

```vb
If tags <> "" Then
    .Write toArray("--" & boundary & vbCrLf)
    .Write toArray("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""tags""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & tags & vbCrLf)
End If
```

Comment: Great catch thank you! I've missed this when re-writing it all.

Comment: One question... What if file being uploaded is of type text/xml? Do we still need to convert its content to binary? Does anyone have an example of how to upload XML file to API service?

Comment: @gdolenc Try something like tis https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473295

Comment: It does not work. I need to upload a file, not only it content. So I need to combine with Content-Disposition header. I need to simulate the following curl:

curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://testapi.valenciaportpcs.net/messaging/messages/upload/default' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer PIjY4ZDJlMzNhLTVlZWMtNDA1Yy04MTNjLWY2N2YxMWJlNmNkNCI=' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'file=@VPRT9000004726.xml;type=text/xml'

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to CDP1802's comment! `VbCrLf` was required instead of `Chr(10)`.

The working section that builds the form data now looks like:

```
Set objADODB = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    
With objADODB
    .Type = 1
    .Open
    
    .Write toArray("--" & boundary & vbCrLf)
    .Write toArray("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""; filename=""" & docFileName & """" & vbCrLf & _
             "Content-Type: " & docContentType & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
    .Write readBinary(docFilePath)
    .Write toArray(vbCrLf & "--" & boundary & vbCrLf)
    .Write toArray("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""material""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & inID & vbCrLf)
    If tags <> "" Then
        .Write toArray("--" & boundary & vbCrLf)
        .Write toArray("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""tags""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & tags & vbCrLf)
    End If
    .Write toArray("--" & boundary & "--")
    .Position = 0
End With
```